# Developer unable to push to protected branch after git reset

Tags: git, gitlab

Can anyone explain why a member of my team is unable to push changes to the master branch (changes that will revet the repo back a few commits) after committing this git reset command:

```
git reset --hard (previous commit SHA)
```

This is the error that was received after attempting git push:

```
 ! [rejected]            master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@xxxxx.com:xxx/xxxx.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

The branch, master, is protected so that only "Developers + Maintainers" can push to it.

My team mate is a member of the Gitlab group in question with "Developer" privileges and has had no issue pushing to the remote repo before. I have Maintainer privileges and also was not able to push to the protected branch and received the same error.

To work around the issue I removed the branch protection and he was able to force push the changes (git push -f).
Does anyone know why this operation fails on a protected branch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've figured out, you can't force push to a protected branch on GitLab.
From [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#overview):

> By default, a protected branch does four simple things:
>
> - It prevents **anyone** from force pushing to the branch.

So your workaround is the solution here: `unprotect` -> `force-push` -> `protect`

**Update**

GitLab added new setting to enable force push to protected:

> - Navigate to your project’s `Settings` > `Repository`.
> - Expand `Protected branches`, and scroll to `Protect a branch`.
> - To allow all users with push access to force push, toggle the `Allow force push` slider.

GitLab now enabled force push to protected branch on [GitLab.com](https://gitlab.com).
On self-managed instances, admins can opt to disable it, so you needs to check with your admin.
Check out more details [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#allow-force-push-on-protected-branches)

Answer (score 18):

You can try allowing force push / deletions from github repo 'settings'

`repository => settings => branches => add rules`

[image]

Comment: Where is the "Allow force pushes" option?

Comment: It's on Git Hub

Comment: I tried to add one of my team members to be whitelisted in allow force pushes, but somehow he was still not able to push force to the protected branch.

Comment: Same here... I've added a team member to the list `Allow force pushes` but looks like it is not working... Am I missing something?

Comment: hard to help if there is error message provided sorry

Answer (score 2):

After the `git reset` command, your local branch is behind the remote branch, and push a branch behind (the remote) directly to the remote is not allowed. If you also need to do the `reset` thing on the remote branch, you need to use `git push -f` to force update the remote branch. Or if the remote branch has some important changes the local branch does not have, then you need to use `git pull` first, solve conflicts, and then you are free to push to the remote.

In Github, when protection of one branch is on, by default, it does not allow force push. There is an option titled "Allow force pushes" in your github repo's `Branch protection rule` page. You can enable this to allow force push to a protected branch.

Answer (score 1):

Commit editing (amend, rebase, filter-branch) or branch pointer moving (reset) require force-push. Protected branches protect from force push:

https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-protected-branches#branch-protection-settings

> When you create a branch protection rule in a repository, **collaborators cannot force push to the protected branch** or delete the branch by default.

(Emphasize by me — phd.)

A member of your team have moved branch pointer so [s]he needs a force-push. That's why you need to remove protection from the branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to sync your Github forked repository, but it failed with a similar error:

> protected branch 'master' check failed: Changes must be made through a
> pull request. Cannot force-push to this branch

A quick resolution could be to temporarily disable branch protection rules in your Github repository settings:
[image]

Then try to sync your fork again:

[image]